# Android studio 3.5 doing gradle build for every debug session

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.5

Every time when we try to debug an app or attach to the running process android studio is triggering a gradle build. Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to build app in order for you to do any debugging. Your files need to be bbuilt from the plain java files to something that can be compiled and understood by the system. YOu can't debug code that has not been built by gradle.

Comment: we are building the code outside of android studio which is why I don't want this build to happen. I found a way to stop this while doing "Debug App" by removing the gradle build task in Before launch section. But that doesn't seem to work when I'm trying to attach to the running process.

Comment: did you find an answer for this?